# How is this date field encoded?

Tags: parsing, date, encoding

I am consuming an REST service that allows me to query a table in a database. There is a date field in that table, but the service is returning the date in a strange format, and I'm unsure how to parse it.

I know for a fact that a certain record's date is `2010/07/16 00:00:00 UTC`, and the string that I get for the date is `1279238400000`. How is this date being encoded? How to I get from that large number to July 7, 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're having is milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a Javascript-style timestamp: milliseconds since Jan 1/1970:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1279238400000 / 1000);
+-------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1279238400000 / 1000) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2010-07-15 18:00:00                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Giving 6pm, July 15th, 2010.